# How to set cookies on Tauri app that works on build? Currently it only works on dev. I am using js-cookie library with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, cookies, tauri

I am very new to Tauri, so I am doing my best to learn. However, I haven't been able to find a solution to this issue online, even though it's supposed to be an easy fix. I have been running Tauri in dev mode and successfully setting cookies with js-cookie (Cookie.set("name", value)). But when I tested it in the build mode, the cookies wouldn't set. When I asked GPT, it suggested doing it in the main.rs file, but I tried following the steps and it didn't work (plus, I don't know any Rust). Can someone please guide me on this? Thank you so much.

I im using react with Tauri.